# Do aircraft using the push pull configuration always use the same engine?

Tags: propulsion

I am currently doing research for a “white paper design” aircraft and I have always been interested in push pull aircraft as they seem to be rare and I wanted to see some challenges in making a very crude and college level aircraft. What I have been wondering is if aircraft in push pull configuration always use the same engine For both the pusher and the puller or is there a advantage in having it be offset where one engine does more of the “work then the other engine?

Comment: No. Just one example: [Rutan Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Voyager).

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14261/are-all-the-engines-on-a-multi-engine-plane-the-same/14262#14262

Comment: Cessna made a few hundred Skymasters. Irreverent nickname "Suck and Blow."